# Why do some androids show permission denied while some dont (both are not rooted)?

Tags: android, adb, android-permissions, root, rooted-device

This is the command I am running via usb

```
adb -s pm disable-user com.instagram.android
```

> Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to
> change component state from pid=21028, uid=2000, package uid=10134

I also tried  `--user 2000` or `--user 0` or `--user 13` without any luck

`adb shell pm list users`

> Users:
> UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running

```
adb -s pm disable-user --user 13 com.instagram.android
```

The above is on **android 5.1 on a Xiaomi Redmi 2 Prime**.

While the same code when run on **android 7.0 on a Motorola Moto C**  works perfectly fine. Both are brand new **non-rooted** phones. What is the difference ? Is there any permission settings that I am missing ?

Answer (score 6):

It's All about manufacturer. Some times some companies make their apps uninstallable or prevent users to disable it. I have a realme 3 Pro and It has `com.nearme.gamecenter` which can't be uninstalled or disabled. My brother has Realme narzo 20 pro. In which the same package is uninstallable. Why companies do this is still a mystry.

though I will suggest trying these commands..

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.instagram.android
```

```
adb shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.instagram.android
```

Comment: Wow, it worked!
I wanted to disable some Google apps on Redmi Note 3 Pro (Android 6), and the second command didn't work... but the first one somehow worked, even without root!